# Read manuscript in to output

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, filesystem-access

I want to put my source plain TeX file in the output of the same plain TeX file.

As I remember coming through a macro, that can put a file's content in to the output, but only `\input` comes to mind. What could it be?

Becoming frustrated—and so tired—I decided, to use the `\openin`, `\read`, `\closein` macros, but failed. For the same file, nothing is read. Only for a text file, the very first line is read, but only if the condition is after the body of the loop.

However, while I was writing this question, a suggestion were showed here, which I learned from that I was missing `\unless`. It is fine, but now everything is interpreted. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\input eplain

This is my plain \TeX{} file that contains a listing of itself.

\listing{\jobname.tex}

\bye
```

The `\listing` command is defined as

```
\def\listing#1{%
   \par \begingroup
   \@setuplisting
   \setuplistinghook
   \input #1
   \endgroup
}%
\let\setuplistinghook = \relax
{%
  \makeactive\^^L
  \let^^L = \relax
  \gdef\@setuplisting{%
     \uncatcodespecials
     \obeywhitespace
     \makeactive\`
     \makeactive\^^I
     \makeactive\^^L
     \def^^L{\vfill\break}%
     \parskip = 0pt
     \listingfont
  }%
}%
```

and this depends on many other definitions. If your file doesn't contain strange things, a simpler definition might work:

```
\def\listing#1{\par\begingroup
  \parindent=0pt
  \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials
  \def\par{\endgraf\leavevmode}%
  \obeyspaces\obeylines\tt
  \input #1 \endgroup}
```

It doesn't work with Spanish inverted marks.

Comment: And it is not possible without eplain, right?

Comment: `eplain.tex` makes available the command. I'll try to look if it's practical to extract the definition.